# Modules installed and working even though PyCharm says they aren't

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pycharm, anaconda

This is probably something I could ignore if I really wanted to, but it's bugging me that this is still happening. I'm just making sure that the modules were installed properly. To test this, I just have a script that prints the versions of each module.

```
import sys
print('Python: {}'.format(sys.version))

import scipy
print('scipy: {}'.format(scipy.__version__))

import numpy
print('numpy: {}'.format(numpy.__version__))

import matplotlib
print('matplotlib: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))

import pandas
print('pandas: {}'.format(pandas.__version__)).

import sklearn
print('sklearn: {}'.format(sklearn.__version__))
```

I'm using PyCharm Community version 2019.3.3, and it's underlining each package name, with the warning "No package named [package]" However, when I run this, I get this output:

```
Python: 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
scipy: 1.4.1
numpy: 1.18.1
matplotlib: 3.1.3
pandas: 1.0.1
sklearn: 0.22.1
```

Showing that everything is working properly. Is there anything I can do about this or should I just ignore it for now?

EDIT: Now that I'm writing using these modules, it's getting a lot worse, especially since these "errors" are counting as part of the total number of errors for the script, so I'll be more likely to miss an actual error.

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? How is your project interpreter configured? We need more information about your development environment.

Comment: I'm new to Python development, so I don't know anything about virtual environments. My interpreter path is C:\Users\(me)\Anaconda3\python.exe

Comment: Is that what you find in the Project Interpreter settings in PyCharm? _I'm new to Python development, so I don't know anything about virtual environments._ The path you just shared indicates that you're using Conda/Anaconda, though.

Comment: Yes, that is the path I have set for the interpreter in PyCharm.

Comment: You might as well make use Conda, if you already have it installed. I’m betting that it will fix this issue.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I’m not the best person to answer that, you should check out the Anaconda/Conda docs.